# Adding comuln/s if not existing using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, psychopy

I am using Pandas with PsychoPy to reorder my results in a dataframe. The problem is that the dataframe is going to vary according to the participant performance. However, I would like to have a common dataframe, where non-existing columns are created as empty. Then the columns have to be in a specific order in the output file.

Let´s suppose I have a dataframe from a participant with the following columns:

```
x = ["Error_1", "Error_2", "Error_3"]
```

I want the final dataframe to look like this:

```
x = x[["Error_1", "Error_2", "Error_3", "Error_4"]]
```

Where `"Error_4"` is created as an empty column.

I tried applying something like this (adapted from another question):

```
if "Error_4" not in x:
    x["Error_4"] = ""

x = x[["Error_1", "Error_2", "Error_3", "Error_4"]]
```

In principle it should work, however I have more or less other 70 columns for which I should do this, and it doesn´t seem practical to do it for each of them.

Do you have any suggestions?

I also tried creating a new dataframe with all the possible columns, e.g.:

```
y = ["Error_1", "Error_2", "Error_3", "Error_4"]
```

However, it is still not clear to me how to merge the dataframes `x` and `y` skipping columns with the same header.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
x = x.reindex(["Error_1", "Error_2", "Error_3", "Error_4"], axis=1, fill_value='')
```

Comment: `x = x.reindex([*x.columns].append("Error_4"), axis=1, fill_value='')`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I followed your suggestion and adapted it. I post it here, since it may be useful for someone else.

First I create a dataframe `y` as I want my output to look like:

```
y = ["Error_1", "Error_2", "Error_3", "Error_4", "Error_5", "Error_6"]
```

Then, I get my actual output file `df` and modify it as `df2`, adding to it all the columns of `y` in the exact same order.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)
columns = df.columns.values.tolist() 
df2 = df.reindex(columns = y, fill_value='')
```

In this case, all the columns that are absent in `df2` but are present in `y`, are going to be added to `df2`.

However, let´s suppose that in `df2` there is a column `"Error_7"` absent in `y`. To keep track of these columns I am just applying `merge` and creating a new dataframe `df3`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df)
df3.to_csv(filename+'UPDATED.csv')
```

The missing columns are going to be added at the end of the dataframe.

If you think this procedure might have drawbacks, or if there is another way to do it, let me know :)